# ssmtp: sending email through the command-line, body of email being ignored

Tags: ssmtp

When I run:

`echo "Subject: mysubject\n\nmytext" | sudo ssmtp myemail@gmail.com`

I expect the line above to send an email to myemail@gmail.com with mysubject as Subject, and mytext as body of the email.

However, it sends an email with `mysubject\n\nmytext` as Subject.

`sudo ssmtp myemail@gmail.com <<<$"Subject: TESTING\n\nBody: of the email. TEST."` has the same problem (that is, packages the whole text as Subject.)

What's wrong? The lines above seem to work for others.

Comment: Not familure with `ssmtp`, but had a similar issue with `sendemail` (note the E). Had to convert subject and body with Base64 to get new lines through. Dont forget to set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`.

Comment: `echo` does not do anything special with `\n` unless (wildly unportable) flags are strewn into to the mix. Try instead `printf(1)` or better yet use `mail(1)` or `mutt(1)`.

Comment: @thrig: `printf "Subject: mysubject\n\nmytext" | sudo ssmtp myemail@gmail.com` instead of `echo ...` works. Thanks